# XSD that requires an attribute but also allows nil

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an XML schema where certain tags must have an `id` attribute.  I can get this working just fine using `use="required"`

```
<xs:element name="SiteDiscoveryReleaseReportReceived">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="ReceivedDate" type="xs:date" nillable="true" />
      <xs:element name="StaffLead" type="xs:int" nillable="true" />
      <xs:element name="Status" nillable="true">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
              <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:int" use="required" />
            </xs:extension>
          </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I also want to make the tag nillable, but the XSD above will not allow me to do `<Status xs:nil="true"/>` because the `id` attribute is missing.  How can I make the `id` attribute required *if* the tag is not nil?  Or is not having an `id` attribute on nil tags going to cause logical problems with xpath queries?

If it matters, this is for an XML column in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have two options:

1. Better one: replace `nillable` attribute with `minOccurs=0`. This way [serializer leaves](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybce7f69%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the `Status` element out entirely if it's value is null.
2. Make `id` attribute `nillable` [as well](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2b314yt2%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Attribute is still enforced to be present though.

Side note: you may have problems deserializing `ReceivedDate` and `StaffLead` elements since "*XmlSerializer throws an exception when it attempts to deserialize an instance of a non-nullable value type if the nil attribute is set to true [1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybce7f69%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*" and `int` and `DateTime` types are non-nullable.